# How to handle all not handled exceptions in @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: exception, spring-boot

I use this exception handler to handle some specific exceptions in my Spring boot application (REST API):

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseMessage notFound(NotFoundException ex) {
        return new NotFoundResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseMessage unsupportedMediaType(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex) {
        return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseMessage unauthorized(UnauthorizedException ex) {
        return new UnauthorizedResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseMessage methodNotAllowed(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        return new MethodNotAllowedResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ForbiddenException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseMessage forbidden(ForbiddenException ex) {
        return new ForbiddenResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

and I would like to handle all the others exceptions with one "global" handling method. But I need to get HTTP status code in this method to process error message etc.

**Question**

Is there some way how to redirect all non-handled exceptions into one particular method? How can I do it?

Comment: Add a method that handles `Exception`. The most specific will be selected for error handling... And simply add the `HttpServletRequest` and/or `HttpServletResponse` as method argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#handlerexceptionresolver):

> Any Spring bean declared in the DispatcherServlet’s application
>   context that implements HandlerExceptionResolver will be used to
>   intercept and process any exception raised in the MVC system and not
>   handled by a Controller.

```
public interface HandlerExceptionResolver {
    ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex);
}
```

Comment: I read this article but I don't need `ModelAndView`, should return my `ResponseMessage` via `@ResponseBody`.